# PHP: Calling a private method from within a class dying badly

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, private-members

So this might sound a little convoluted.  Fingers crossed I come across clearly.

I'm working in an MVC framework in PHP.

I load a controller /report/index which calls to a helper

```
<? class ReportController extends Controller { 
        public function index() {
            $foo = MainReport::get_data($_REQUEST);
        }

   }
 ?>
```

Inside the helper

```
<? class MainReport extends foo {
        public function get_data($_REQUEST) {
            // do stuff
            return $stuff_done;
        }

 }
?>
```

It I run it like ^this all's well and good.  Unfortunately, I want to run it like this:

```
<? class MainReport extends foo {
        private function do_stuff() { 
            // do even better stuff here!
            return $better_stuff;
        }
        public function get_data($_REQUEST) {
            // do stuff
            $x = $this->do_stuff();    
        }

 }
?>
```

Unfortunately... when I try and call a private function from within a class that I've called from elsewhere... (whew, that's a mouthful) ... everything dies.  Dies so very very badly that I don't even get an error.

It seems obvious to me that I'm having an incredibly dorky sort of syntax issue of some sort... but how do I correctly access private functions from within a class?

Maybe something like: 
    self::do_stuff();

What about declaring and accessing private class variables?

```
 private $bar = array();
```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling your function from a static context,

```
MainReport::get_data($_REQUEST)
```

therefore $this does not exist while inside that function.

If you want to call another class function while inside a static context, you have to also call it statically.

i.e.

```
public function get_data($_REQUEST) {
        // do stuff
        $x = MainReport::do_stuff();    
    }
```

Alternatively, you can create an instance of your class in the original call and use the instance:

```
$myMainReport = new MainReport();
$myMainReport->get_data($_REQUEST);
```

Then your class code will work as expected

Comment: shouldn't it be "public static function get_data($_REQUEST)" ?

Comment: you can call a function in php statically as long as it doesn't depend on class vars or instance based method calls

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that self:: does work as well

if I want to have private class variables, I can declare and access them using

```
private static $foo
```

and

```
self::$foo = "foo";
```

additionally a private function can be accessed with

```
self::function_foo();
```