# How to access a private property/method?

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, private

I'm new to OOP programming and i'm trying to set up a private class db, for database connection:

My class:

```
class db
{
private $_db;

private function db()   
{
$this->db = new mysqli('localhost','x','x','x');
$this->db->set_charset('utf');
}
}
```

In another file I have the following code:

```
$db = new db();
                $sql = "SELECT news, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%D %b') AS date FROM news ORDER       
BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y, %m, %d') DESC LIMIT 3";
                $r = $db->db->query($sql);
                while($row=$r->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo '<b>'. $row['date'] . '</b></br> ' . $row['news'] .'</br>   
</br>';
                }
```

It works grand for public but not for private.

I was reading that private methods can only be accessed within the class but can't really understand how to do it. Can anyone please give me a hint?

Regards
Jack

Comment: That is why there are private variables. You can't access them directly. Provide getters for them. E.g. `public function getDB() { return $this->_db; }` Private methods can be refered only within the class.

Comment: Private methods and properties are **not** accessible externally.

Comment: Also you should be using `__construct()` as your constructor method name not the old way of naming the constructor that same as the class.  Likely you do not want the constructor to be private unless you are trying to implement a singleton.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php Explains it all with examples. Vote to close

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Look at the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3662658/3005071

Comment: makes sense; thanks for that. still need to spend some time to fully comprehend it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your method is private. Essentially, any methods you want to use external to the class should be public. This leads to the creation of getters and setters.

Getters return private variable fields and setters set those fields to new values. This is just a safe way to enforce types and cleanly accept class modification.

Comment: ok; maybe i understand it in a wrong way; i though it had to do with the security of your code? Sorry if my questions sound perplexing but i'm new to OOP and i'm trying to get my head around various concepts. Is it ok to use public for all methods and properties and does it impact the system security in any way? Shouldn't i keep my database connection class as private to increase the security?

Comment: @Jack Yes and no. Public methods are used for variable fields you know other classes need access to. For instance, if I have a variable that says how many entries are in my database, I may want a public getter for that. However, the code that creates my database inside a class may be private because I don't want it callable outside my class. It's not security per-se, but more so safety of code. It tells other who might use your code what they can and can't do (safely) with it.

Comment: Cheers Dylan, would it be a bad practice though to declare all your classes as public? Also will my website be less secure if I do so? In my example I don't really know how I could make the db class work as private.

Comment: Public and private don't really create web security. Generally, yes, most classes themselves are public, due to a necessity to access the classes themselves. It's more about methods and variables than classes. (Though you can have private inner classes and other special case things.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the key principles of OOP is separation of interface from implementation. Class can be represented as a black box, where public methods and properties are used by the outer world to interact with your box.

While the private methods and properties are internal and are used to implement the functionality.

There is no need to make `function db()` private, as connection to the database must be provided as a function to the outer world by your class.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods and private properties only reachable inside the same class (scope). The usage of private properties and methods should be well considered, private methods or private properites avoids any kind of reachability or inheritability by the heirs of the defining class.

Protected methods and private properties only reachable inside the same class and it heirs. Protected methods and privates are recommend for class-internal logic and their properties.